# Can't Merge Lists properly in Python - last element isn't getting merged

Tags: python, list, methods, replace, merge

There are two lists:

```py
MAIN: ['Lists ', '\nThe first list', '\n 4. Empty', '\n 5. Orange', '\n 6. Lemon', '\n 7. 2 Tangerines']
FOR REPLACEMENT: ['The second list is', '\n3. Apple ', '\n4. Banana ', '\n5. Pear', '\n8. Milk']
```

How to write a condition in this code so that the 8th element is not lost?

```
a = ['Lists', 'The first list', '4. Empty', '5. Empty', '6. Lemon', '7. 2 Tangerines']
b = ['The second list is', '3. Apple ', '4. Banana ', '5. Pear', '8. Other']
w = []
for i in range(len(a)):    # find all the unnumbered elements of the first list, add them to the final one in order
    if a[i][0] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
        w.append('0. ' + a[i])
    else:
        n = i
        break
for i in range(len(b)):     # find all the unnumbered elements of the second list, also add them to the final one in order
    if b[i][0] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
        w.append('0. ' + b[i])
    else:
        m = i
        break
w += a[n:]      # adding the numbered elements of the first list
for i in range(m, len(b)):      # we check the numbered elements of the second list, do the necessary action(replace/add)
    for j in range(len(w)):
        if b[i][:b[i].index('.')] == w[j][:w[j].index('.')]:
            w[j] = b[i]
            break
        elif int(b[i][:b[i].index('.')]) < int(w[j][:w[j].index('.')]):
            w = w[:j] + [b[i]] + w[j:]
            break
k = 0       # beautiful output
while w[k][0] == '0':
    w[k] = w[k][3:]
    k += 1
print('\n'.join(w))
```

It is necessary to replace the elements of the first list with elements from the second.

In the first list, the numbers always go in order. In the second, this may not be. If there is a number in the second list that is not in the main one, then it should be inserted at the top or bottom, respectively.

I can't output elements 8. 9. 10. and so on. Simply put, the elements from the end are not inserted into the main list.
Expected result:

```
Lists
The first list
The second list is
3. Apple
4. Banana
5. Pear
6. Lemon
7. 2 Tangerines
8. Other
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for i in range(len(list)):` Use `for item in list:`

Comment: And if you need the indexes for something else: `for i, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a = ['Lists', 'The first list', '4. Empty', '5. Empty', '6. Lemon', '7. 2 Tangerines']
b = ['The second list is', '3. Apple ', '4. Banana ', '5. Pear', '8. Other']

x = sorted([
    x for x in a+b
    if x[0].isdigit() and x[3:] != 'Empty'
    ], key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
for x in x: print(x)
```